# How can I secure the Facebook login?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I've integrated Facebook login to my AngularJS application. The user can login and from that login I get the users ID and an access token.

But I guess I further have to secure my API as anyone, now, could do request with a number (ID) and a token (string) and get access.

My backend is a ASP.NET Web API project.

Is there a service from Facebook (API) that I can call to verify access token and user id? Or do I have to implement some sort of request token system to verify that the client is one of mine?

Any comments on how to verify my clients?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/) ?
Login Security guideline for fb.